# Adding custom telemetry to Azure Isolated Worker process' application insights

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am working with [Azure Durable Functions Isolated Worker Processes](https://github.com/microsoft/durabletask-dotnet/tree/v1.0.1) and would like to set custom telemetry data to all logs I send to Azure Application Insights. I have followed [the guide in Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer) and a few blog posts but still no luck.

Here is my csconfig:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.7.0" OutputItemType="Analyzer" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DurableTask.Generators" Version="1.0.0-preview.1" OutputItemType="Analyzer" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Program.cs:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
.ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
{
    services
        .AddHttpClient()
        .AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, CustomTelemetry>();
})
.Build();

host.Run();
```

CustomTelemetry.cs:

```
public class CustomTelemetry : ITelemetryInitializer
{
public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
{
    telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties.Add("GlobalProperties", "FromCustomTelemetryYeeeeeeyyy");

    if (telemetry is TraceTelemetry traceTelemetry)
    {
        traceTelemetry.Context.GlobalProperties.Add("GlobalProperties", "FromCustomTelemetryYeeeeeeyyy");
        traceTelemetry.Properties.Add("CustomTraceTelemetry", "FromCustomTelemetryYeeeeeeyyy");
    }

    if(telemetry is ISupportProperties itemProperties)
    {
        itemProperties.Properties["customProp"] = "customValue";
    }

    if (telemetry is RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry)
    {
        requestTelemetry.Context.GlobalProperties.Add("GlobalProperties", "FromCustomTelemetryYeeeeeeyyy");
        requestTelemetry.Properties.Add("LoggedInUserName", "DummyUser");
    }
}
}
```

Function:

```
public class Hello
{
private readonly ILogger<Hello> _logger;

public Hello(ILogger<Hello> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}

[Function(nameof(StartDisplayCorrelationId))]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> StartDisplayCorrelationId(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
    [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
    FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    var log = executionContext.GetLogger(nameof(StartDisplayCorrelationId));
    log.LogInformation("LOGGER FROM EXECUTION CONTEXT AND IT IS HERE.........................................");
    
    var correlationId = CorrelationIdMiddleware.GetCorrelationId(req);
    
    var instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(nameof(CorrelationIdOrchestrator), correlationId);
    _logger.LogInformation("Created new orchestration with instance ID = {InstanceId}", instanceId);

    return client.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
}

[Function(nameof(CorrelationIdOrchestrator))]
public async Task<string> CorrelationIdOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
{
    var input = context.GetInput<string>();
    return await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(CorrelationIdActivity), input);
}

[Function(nameof(CorrelationIdActivity))]
public string CorrelationIdActivity([ActivityTrigger] string correlationId, FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("CorrelationIdActivity started................................................");
    _logger.LogInformation("CorrelationId: {CorrelationId}", correlationId);
    return $"Hello, {correlationId}!";
}
}
```

So neither `log.LogInformation` nor `_logger.LogInformation` sends any custom telemetry to Azure Application Insights.

Expected behavior is similar to:

[image: CustomPropertiesOfAzureApplicationInsights]